# making a cone roof look hollow

Tags: opengl

How can I make a cone roof look hollow when viewed from underneath?

I am trying to create a cone shaped roof, but the cone does not look much like a roof,
the edges of the roof seem to blend with the rest of the cone.

How can I make the cone look more like a "roof"? is making it look hollow the best way?

This is how I am drawing the cone:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 2.5);
    glColor3f(255, 0.0, 0.0);
    glutSolidCone(1.75, 1, 32, 16);
glPopMatrix();
```

This is what my scene looks like:

[image]

Here is my complete source code:

```
// gcc -o snowman snowman.c -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL


#include <stdlib.h> // standard definitions
#include <math.h> // math definitions
#include <stdio.h> // standard I/O

// include files are in a slightly different location for MacOS
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

// escape key (for exit)
#define ESC 27


// Camera position
float x = 0.0, y = -5.0; // initially 5 units south of origin
float deltaMove = 0.0; // initially camera doesn't move

// Camera direction
float lx = 0.0, ly = 1.0; // camera points initially along y-axis
float angle = 0.0; // angle of rotation for the camera direction
float deltaAngle = 0.0; // additional angle change when dragging

// Mouse drag control
int isDragging = 0; // true when dragging
int xDragStart = 0; // records the x-coordinate when dragging starts

void changeSize(int w, int h) 
{
    float ratio =  ((float) w) / ((float) h); // window aspect ratio
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // projection matrix is active
    glLoadIdentity(); // reset the projection
    gluPerspective(45.0, ratio, 0.1, 100.0); // perspective transformation
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // return to modelview mode
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h); // set viewport (drawing area) to entire window
}


void drawSnowman()
{
    // Draw body (a 20x20 spherical mesh of radius 0.75 at height 0.75)
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // set drawing color to white
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.75);
        glutSolidSphere(0.75, 20, 20);
    glPopMatrix();

    // Draw the head (a sphere of radius 0.25 at height 1.75)
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 1.70); // position head
        glutSolidSphere(0.25, 20, 20); // head sphere

        // Draw Eyes (two small black spheres)
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // eyes are black
        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(0.0, -0.18, 0.10); // lift eyes to final position
            glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(-0.05, 0.0, 0.0);
                glutSolidSphere(0.05, 10, 10); // right eye
            glPopMatrix();
            glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(+0.05, 0.0, 0.0);
                glutSolidSphere(0.05, 10, 10); // left eye
            glPopMatrix();
        glPopMatrix();

        // Draw Nose (the nose is an orange cone)
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.5, 0.5); // nose is orange
        glPushMatrix();
            glRotatef(90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // rotate to point along -y
            glutSolidCone(0.08, 0.5, 10, 2); // draw cone
        glPopMatrix();


    glPopMatrix();

    // Draw a faux shadow beneath snow man (dark green circle)
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.2, 0.2, 0.001);  // translate to just above ground
        glScalef(1.0, 1.0, 0.0); // scale sphere into a flat pancake
        glutSolidSphere(0.75, 20, 20); // shadow same size as body
    glPopMatrix();


    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glScalef(1.0, 40.0, 1.0);
        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glutSolidCube(0.125);
    glPopMatrix();

    // Draw the roof posts using cylinders
    GLUquadricObj *quadratic;
    quadratic = gluNewQuadric();

    // post 1
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    gluCylinder(quadratic, 0.075, 0.075, 2.5, 32,32);
    glPopMatrix();

    // post 2
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    gluCylinder(quadratic, 0.075, 0.075, 2.5, 32,32);
    glPopMatrix();

    // post 3
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    gluCylinder(quadratic, 0.075, 0.075, 2.5, 32,32);
    glPopMatrix();

    // post 4
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    gluCylinder(quadratic, 0.075, 0.075, 2.5, 32,32);
    glPopMatrix();


    // draw roof using a cone
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 2.5);
        glColor3f(255, 0.0, 0.0);
        glutSolidCone(1.75, 1, 32, 16);
    glPopMatrix();

}


void update(void) 
{
    if (deltaMove) { // update camera position
        x += deltaMove * lx * 0.1;
        y += deltaMove * ly * 0.1;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay(); // redisplay everything
}


void renderScene(void) 
{
    int i, j;

    // Clear color and depth buffers
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.7, 1.0, 1.0); // sky color is light blue
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Reset transformations
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Set the camera centered at (x,y,1) and looking along directional
    // vector (lx, ly, 0), with the z-axis pointing up
    gluLookAt(
            x,      y,      1.0,
            x + lx, y + ly, 1.0,
            0.0,    0.0,    1.0);

    // Draw ground - 200x200 square colored green
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.7, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(-100.0, -100.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(-100.0,  100.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f( 100.0,  100.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f( 100.0, -100.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    // Draw 36 snow men
    for(i = -3; i < 3; i++)
        for(j = -3; j < 3; j++) {
            glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(i*7.5, j*7.5, 0);
                drawSnowman();
            glPopMatrix();
        }

    glutSwapBuffers(); // Make it all visible
} 

// processNormalKeys: ESC, q, and Q cause program to exit
// pressSpecialKey: Up arrow = forward motion, down arrow = backwards
// releaseSpecialKey: Set incremental motion to zero
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
void processNormalKeys(unsigned char key, int xx, int yy)
{
    if (key == ESC || key == 'q' || key == 'Q') exit(0);
} 

void pressSpecialKey(int key, int xx, int yy)
{
    switch (key) {
        case GLUT_KEY_UP : deltaMove = 1.0; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN : deltaMove = -1.0; break;
    }
} 

void releaseSpecialKey(int key, int x, int y) 
{
    switch (key) {
        case GLUT_KEY_UP : deltaMove = 0.0; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN : deltaMove = 0.0; break;
    }
} 


void mouseMove(int x, int y) 
{   
    if (isDragging) { // only when dragging
        // update the change in angle
        deltaAngle = (x - xDragStart) * 0.005;

        // camera's direction is set to angle + deltaAngle
        lx = -sin(angle + deltaAngle);
        ly = cos(angle + deltaAngle);
    }
}

void mouseButton(int button, int state, int x, int y) 
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) {
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN) { // left mouse button pressed
            isDragging = 1; // start dragging
            xDragStart = x; // save x where button first pressed
        }
        else  { /* (state = GLUT_UP) */
            angle += deltaAngle; // update camera turning angle
            isDragging = 0; // no longer dragging
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    printf("\n\
-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n\
   Controls \n\
  - Drag mouse left-right to rotate camera\n\
  - Hold up-arrow/down-arrow to move camera forward/backward\n\
  - q or ESC to quit\n\
-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    // general initializations
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(1200, 800);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL/GLUT Sampe Program");

    // register callbacks
    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize); // window reshape callback
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene); // (re)display callback
    glutIdleFunc(update); // incremental update 
    glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(1); // ignore key repeat when holding key down
    glutMouseFunc(mouseButton); // process mouse button push/release
    glutMotionFunc(mouseMove); // process mouse dragging motion
    glutKeyboardFunc(processNormalKeys); // process standard key clicks
    glutSpecialFunc(pressSpecialKey); // process special key pressed
                        // Warning: Nonstandard function! Delete if desired.
    glutSpecialUpFunc(releaseSpecialKey); // process special key release

    // OpenGL init
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // enter GLUT event processing cycle
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the cone drawn by `glutSolidCone` is not capped, but then if you don't have any lighting, all the pixels for that cone look red, and there's no way for the viewer to know if it's capped or not. How about adding some lighting to the scene?

Comment: .. or manually add a darker circle beneath the cone.

Comment: that looks very flat. how about a bit of shading(perhaps toon shading) ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza ok, thanks for the suggestion! What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Since you're using a lighthouse 3d tutorial, also look for their toon shader tutorial by Philip Rideout

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using more modern openGL programming.  You method using the matrix stack and glutSolidCone is difficult to maintain, to test and to customize.

To give the feeling of volume of your cone, you should use classical painting techniques : lighting (written using a simple shader, this can still look very cartoon-like) or paint the edges (using the GL_LINES drawing mode on the boundary edges).